# Find occurrence of substring in sentence only if word starts with substring

Tags: iphone, ios, nspredicate

If I have 2 strings:
"My name is Eric"
"America is great"

And my substring is 'eri'.

How can I write a function that will only return true for the first sentence, because it has a WORD that starts with eri (Eric) and does not just contain eri (AmERIca).

Note;
I have been using NSPredicates, but using CONTAINS would return both, and using BEGINSWITH would only check the first word.

This string is also contained in an Object, say  and the property is called ,
so my current code is:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

searchResults = [[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: You might have to actually do some programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not search for a string with leading space, like " eri"? That will automatically only find actual words and not something in the middle.

Comment: because what if its the first word of the sentence, in which case it wont have a space

Comment: Why shouldn't it? As far as I know, all words and sentences start with leading space (just look at any text). One exception here is the very first sentence in your string, because it doesn't have any leading space, but you can check that case using beginsWith method.

Comment: Sure Ill give it to you, I just checked for both @" eri" and @"eri", because my sentences will not start with a space. Thanks!