# Matching set of words that start by a specific string using predicate

Tags: ios, predicate

I would like to know if it is possible to filter an array which contain multiple set of words to obtain a filtered array that contains only words that start with a string using predicates:

I guess an example will talk by himself:

Array:

- green pepper
- white grapes

Filtered array for the @"pe"

- green pepper

Currently i am applying one predicate like the following:

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
  NSArray *tempArray = [[self.searchContent objectAtIndex:INGREDIENT] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
  [self.ingredientsFiltered addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
```

but this will give me both green pepper and white grapes as @"pe" is also a substring of pepper. Is there any recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: How about a combination of `"SELF BEGINSWITH pe"` and `"SELF contains[c] %@", @" pe"` which is joined by an `OR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*",searchText]];
```

Comment: no it will not work because you are applying the predicate on the whole string e.g @"green pepper" instead of words within the string

Comment: my question is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767936/find-occurrence-of-substring-in-sentence-only-if-word-starts-with-substring but this is not sastisfying

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it now.

Comment: @tiguero, Check this, http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html. It is for word boundary. But I was able to get the filtered array with first approach. What was the issue with the earlier one?

Comment: in your first approach i was still picking up a substring in the middle of a word. Are u sure it shouldn't be AND as you first suggested?

Comment: @tiguero, That is weird, because I tried the same code and I was able to filter using that before I posted. Anyways thanks for accepting.

Comment: with the OR or AND version i can give a try again i am curious

Comment: @tiguero, I will also check, because I am still getting proper filtered array with that.

Comment: i think i know why was the space intentional: @" %@" i guess yes

Comment: @tiguero, yes, you need that space to represent the word boundary. So that is also a correct answer then. Anyways this should be fine.